# Vuex action doesn't fetch data from API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, store, vuex

I'm trying to fetch some data from a local API using [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server), but my Vuex actions doesn't fetch the data.

the testing server doesn't show any GET request and my vue app can't render anything.

when a run `npm run dev` it compiles all my assets without errors but if i check the vue-dev-tools it show the state as an empty array.

i don't know what am i doing wrong.

#### Products module:

**products.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api_home = 'http://localhost:8069/'

const state = {
    products: []
}

const getters = {
    getAllProducts: (state) => {
        return state.products
    },
    getFeaturedProducts: (state) => {
        return state.products.featured
    },
    getDealsProducts: (state) => {
        return state.products.deals
    },
    getQueryProducts: (state) => {
        return state.products.query
    }
}

const actions = {
    async fetchProducts({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(`${api_home}products/`)
        console.log(response.data)
    }
}

const mutations = {
    setProducts: (state, list) => {
        state.products = list
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import products from './modules/products'
import ads from './modules/ads'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        products,
        ads
    }
})
```

And this is the **script** portion of my component:

```
<script>
/* Vuex import */
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
/* Swiper */
import 'swiper/dist/css/swiper.css'
import { swiper, swiperSlide } from 'vue-awesome-swiper'
/* Componentes internos */
import baseSearchComponent from '../base/baseSearchComponent'

export default {
    name: 'page-home-component',
    components: {
        swiper,
        swiperSlide,
        baseSearchComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            swiperOption: {
            }
        }
    },
    methods: mapActions([
            'fetchProducts',
            'fetchAds'
        ]),
    computed: mapGetters([
            'getFeaturedProducts',
            'getDealsProducts',
            'getBanners'
        ]),
    created() {
        this.fetchProducts,
        this.fetchAds
    },
}
</script>
```

I expected an array of objects in `state.products` but all my getters are empty.

Comment: You're not actually calling `this.fetchProducts`, you need to call it like `this.fetchProducts()`, same for `this.fetchAds`

Comment: @EricGuan i've though i cloudn't be so stupid... but once again i surprice my self... Thanks you very much, after this i got a "reference" error. Adding `"plugins": ["transform-runtime", {"polyfill": false,"regenerator": true}]]` solves the problem